# Java, Android: Activity not found exception when exporting

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

I am creating this game for android with java. It works like it should but when I export it and send it to others it gives the activity not found exception, does anyone know why?

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements Constants
{
    private GameView mGameView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mGameView = new GameView(this, getAssets());
        setContentView(mGameView);

        ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
        mGameView.setMemoryLimit(am.getMemoryClass());
    }
}
```

And here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testcompany.testgame" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Care to explain *how* you export? Do you create an APK? Have you tried to clean before you build?

Comment: Yes, I am exporting an .apk and I have tried to clean the project.

Comment: Please add the logcat stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not using Proguard improperly which may cause the Activity class to get obfuscated and thus not be found. To do this make sure your `proguard.cfg` file contains:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

<s>Check that your `Main` activity is located in the `com.testcompany.testgame` package (i.e. the `package` declaration at the top of Main.java). If you are using a subpackage then you need to include that in your AndroidManifest.xml file.</s>

Answer (score 0):

unchecke Android Dependencies from Project--> Properties-->Java builder Path-->android dependencies